# Grails Unit Testing a method with command object

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock, command-objects

I have a problem with my Unit Test. This is my Unit Test:

```
void "Test the update action performs an update on a valid domain instance"() {
    given:
        def aclServiceMock = mockFor(AclService)
        aclServiceMock.demand.updateRolePermissions { Role role, Map, roleMap, List permissions -> return true }
        controller.aclService = aclServiceMock.createMock()

        def roleInstance = setupRoleController()

        mockCommandObject RoleCommand
        RoleCommand cmd = new RoleCommand(
            authority: roleInstance?.authority,
            description: roleInstance?.description
        )

    when:"A valid domain instance is passed to the update action"
        controller.update(roleInstance, cmd)

    then:"A redirect is issued to the show action"
        response.redirectedUrl == "/role/index"
        flash.message != null
        flash.error == null
}
```

And this is the result that I get from the terminal:

```
| Failure:  Test the update action performs an update on a valid domain instance(ph.gov.doe.core.acl.RoleControllerSpec)
|  Condition not satisfied:
flash.message != null
|     |       |
[:]   null    false
    at ph.gov.doe.core.acl.RoleControllerSpec.Test the update action performs an update on a valid domain instance(RoleControllerSpec.groovy:222)
```

I can't seem to figure out why my unit test on that particular method keeps failing. Maybe my Command Object mock is the key? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: condition should be 'response.redirectedUrl == "/role/index"', I just copied the wrong message cause i was fiddling with the code at the time.

EDIT: This is the controller method:

```
def update(Role roleInstance, RoleCommand roleCommand) {
    Map roleMap = [:]
    ArrayList collectPermission = [], getPermissions = [], roleList = []
    def savedRoleInstance

    /** collect selected permission into arraylist */
    collectPermission.addAll(params?.selectedPermission ?: [])
    getPermissions = Permission.findAllByIdInList(collectPermission)

    def roleEditInstance = Role.get(params?.roleId)

    /** Set data for validation of Role */
    roleCommand.with {
        id          = roleEditInstance?.id
        authority   = params?.authority
        description = params?.description
    }

    roleCommand.validate()        

    /** Check if the set of permission already exists */
    roleList = RolePermission.findAllByPermissionInListAndRoleNotEqual(getPermissions, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_SUPERADMIN'))?.role

    def duplicateRolePermission = roleList.find { r -> r.getAuthorities().sort { it?.id } == getPermissions.sort { it?.id }  && r != roleEditInstance }

    if (collectPermission.isEmpty()) {
        flash.error = message(code: 'role.permissions.blank', args: [message(code: 'role.label', default: params?.authority)])
        respond roleInstance, model:[roleList: Role.list(), permissionList: Permission.findAllByAuthorityNotEqual('PERM_DASHBOARD_VIEW'), inheritPermission: params?.inheritPermission, selectedPermission: getPermissions], view: "edit"            
    } else if (roleCommand.hasErrors() || duplicateRolePermission != null) {
        bindData(roleCommand, roleInstance)

        if(duplicateRolePermission != null){
            flash.error = message(code: 'role.permissions.unique', args: [message(code: 'role.label', default: getPermissions?.description)])
        }

        respond roleCommand.errors, model:[roleInstance: roleCommand,roleList: Role.list(), permissionList: Permission.findAllByAuthorityNotEqual('PERM_DASHBOARD_VIEW'), inheritPermission: params?.inheritPermission, selectedPermission: getPermissions, roleId: roleEditInstance?.id], view: "edit"
    } else {
        /** Save the Role */
        roleMap = [authority: params?.authority, description: params?.description]
        def savedRole = aclService.updateRolePermissions(roleEditInstance, roleMap, getPermissions)

        if (currentAccount) {
           auditLogService.logEvent(currentAccount.emailAddress, "UPDATE_ROLE_SUCCESS", "Successfully updated role details.", true) 
        }

        flash.message = message(code: 'role.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'role.label', default: savedRole?.authority)])
        flash.id = savedRole?.id
        redirect action: 'view', params:[id: savedRole?.id]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your controller code as well?

Comment: oh, yeah, sorry. i'll edit the post.

Comment: Wow, you have a lot going on in that controller method. :) 

I suspect that part of your issue is the params in this line do not match the actual signature of your method in your AclService:
`aclServiceMock.demand.updateRolePermissions { Role role, Map, roleMap, List permissions -> return true }` and so it is not using your mock. 


Try removing the extra comma after Map:
`aclServiceMock.demand.updateRolePermissions { Role role, Map roleMap, List permissions -> return true }`

Comment: @LeslieV oh, yeah. shoot. that's so clumsy. thanks for pointing that out. i tried running the test again, but still no luck. i'm getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the app you're trying to test could be designed better. Lots of logic could be moved from controller to service ([separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle).

Also your test looks like integration-test rather then unit. So I would recommend you to get acquainted with [interaction based testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html).

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, we're still in the process of improving everything, and we'll focus on making it more efficient once we've got the mehods working. And you're right, I think we'll be using integration testing instead. Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend to use unit, integration and functional tests at the same time.

Here is a doc: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll definitely bring that up to the team. Thank you!